# FOSUserBundle make a field required

Tags: php, symfony, field, fosuserbundle

I work with Symfony 2 and FOSUserBundle. I have now added some fields in my User entity. Maintant, I will wish to make something mandatory (as the default e-mail fields).

Here is my code:

```
# src/FP/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    FP_user.registration.form.type:
        class: FP\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: fp_user_registration }
    FP.util.user_manipulator:
        class:      FP\UserBundle\Util\UserManipulator
        arguments:  [@fos_user.user_manager]
```

.

```
<?php

namespace FP\UserBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand as BaseCommand;

class CreateUserCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        exit;
        parent::configure();
        $this
            ->setName('fp:user:create')
            ->getDefinition()->addArguments(array(
                new InputArgument('age', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The age')
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        exit;
        $username   = $input->getArgument('username');
        $email      = $input->getArgument('email');
        $password   = $input->getArgument('password');
        $age        = $input->getOption('age');
        $inactive   = $input->getOption('inactive');
        $superadmin = $input->getOption('super-admin');

        $manipulator = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_user.util.user_manipulator');
        $manipulator->create($username, $password, $email, $age, !$inactive, $superadmin);

        $output->writeln(sprintf('Created user <comment>%s</comment>', $username));
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        exit;
        parent::interact($input, $output);
        if (!$input->getArgument('age')) {
            $age = $this->getHelper('dialog')->askAndValidate(
                $output,
                'Please choose a age:',
                function($age) {
                    if (empty($age)) {
                        throw new \Exception('Lastname can not be empty');
                    }

                    return $age;
                }
            );
            $input->setArgument('age', $age);
        }
    }
}
<?php

namespace FP\UserBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand as BaseCommand;

class CreateUserCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        exit;
        parent::configure();
        $this
            ->setName('fp:user:create')
            ->getDefinition()->addArguments(array(
                new InputArgument('age', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The age')
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        exit;
        $username   = $input->getArgument('username');
        $email      = $input->getArgument('email');
        $password   = $input->getArgument('password');
        $age        = $input->getOption('age');
        $inactive   = $input->getOption('inactive');
        $superadmin = $input->getOption('super-admin');

        $manipulator = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_user.util.user_manipulator');
        $manipulator->create($username, $password, $email, $age, !$inactive, $superadmin);

        $output->writeln(sprintf('Created user <comment>%s</comment>', $username));
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        exit;
        parent::interact($input, $output);
        if (!$input->getArgument('age')) {
            $age = $this->getHelper('dialog')->askAndValidate(
                $output,
                'Please choose a age:',
                function($age) {
                    if (empty($age)) {
                        throw new \Exception('Lastname can not be empty');
                    }

                    return $age;
                }
            );
            $input->setArgument('age', $age);
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
<?php

namespace FP\UserBundle\Util;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\UserManipulator as Manipulator;

/**
 * Executes some manipulations on the users
 *
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 * @author Luis Cordova <cordoval@gmail.com>
 */
class UserManipulator extends Manipulator
{
    /**
     * User manager
     *
     * @var UserManagerInterface
     */
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a user and returns it.
     *
     * @param string  $username
     * @param string  $password
     * @param string  $email
     * @param string  $age
     * @param Boolean $active
     * @param Boolean $superadmin
     *
     * @return \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface
     */
    public function create($username, $password, $email, $age, $active, $superadmin, age)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setName($age);
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $user->setEnabled((Boolean)$active);
        $user->setSuperAdmin((Boolean)$superadmin);
        $user->setAge($age);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

I tried to follow the path traveled between files during the validation of my form. I noticed that it does not go through the commands *FP\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand.php* nor *FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand.php*. So obviously it can not notice the change made. Only, how does one make him notice?

There is my User Entity:

```
<?php
// src/FP/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace FP\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sexe", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sexe;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="integer")
     */
    private $age;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pays", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pays;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateInscrip", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateInscrip;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set sexe
     *
     * @param string $sexe
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSexe($sexe)
    {
        $this->sexe = $sexe;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sexe
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSexe()
    {
        return $this->sexe;
    }

    /**
     * Set age
     *
     * @param integer $age
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get age
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    /**
     * Set pays
     *
     * @param string $pays
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPays($pays)
    {
        $this->pays = $pays;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pays
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPays()
    {
        return $this->pays;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param string $status
     * @return User
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateInscrip
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateInscrip
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDateInscrip($dateInscrip)
    {
        $this->dateInscrip = $dateInscrip;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateInscrip
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateInscrip()
    {
        return $this->dateInscrip;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \FP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image $image
     * @return User
     */
    public function setImage(\FP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \FP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to make then mandatory when a user is filling the form ? or from the console command ?

Comment: Can you post you User entity code? What about Doctrine Asserts?

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaB I would do it from the console.